# Copy a object properties to another in TypeScript, cause error TS2339

Tags: types, typescript, extend, typescript1.6

I use a `extend()` function to extend a object:

```
function extend(obj: Object, extension: Object) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        try {
            extension[key] = obj[key];
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And there is a class `Observer()` hava a method `Update()` and a object `check` which is `HTMLInputElement` type.

```
class Observer {
    Update(value) { }
}
var check:HTMLInputElement = document.createElement("input");
```

I use `extend()` function to extend `checkbox`,so it would have the method `Update()`.

```
extend(new Observer(), check);
check.Update = function(value) {
    this.checked = value;
}
```

And then cause error TS2339:`Property 'Update' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'`
[image]

How to Fixed this error? Change the `extend()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a good scenario for an [intersection type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1256)?

```
function extend<T, U>(obj: T, extension: U) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        extension[key] = obj[key];
    });

    return extension as T & U;
}

var check: HTMLInputElement;
var extended = extend(new Observer(), check);

// example HTMLInputElement property use
extended.attributes;
// no compile error here either:
extended.Update = function(value) {
    this.checked = value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following code snippet, what you are looking for?

```
class Observer extends HTMLInputElement{
    Update: any;
}

var check:Observer = <Observer>document.createElement("input");

check.Update = function(value) {
    this.checked = value;
}
```